# Ubuntu 22.04.4 screen issue

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04, display-resolution

I have the problem while booting as you see in the photograph below once I log in and choose refresh rate as 60 Hz there is no any problem, but when I choose 120Hz there is a problem. I tried every way that I found on internet, but nothing helped.

[image]